# React table - Dropdown filter

Tags: react-table

I have implemented Global Filer using setGlobalFilter

[image]

But I want to Set filter column wise like:

Outside the table, I need a dropdown with some values which should filter the react-table based on the opted value from the dropdown.
this dropdown filter should filter out the whole table based on the opted value from the dropdown.

[image]

Can anyone give me link of demo or any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, let's do it on **react-table v8**, yes, it is the new version of react-table.

First, make sure you import the required items from `@tanstack/react-table`

```js
import {
  createColumnHelper,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  getFilteredRowModel,
  useReactTable,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
```

Here, we use simple data.

```js
const defaultData = [
  {
    firstName: "tanner",
    lastName: "linsley",
    age: 24,
    visits: 100,
    status: "In Relationship",
    progress: 50,
  },
  {
    firstName: "tandy",
    lastName: "miller",
    age: 40,
    visits: 40,
    status: "Single",
    progress: 80,
  },
  {
    firstName: "joe",
    lastName: "dirte",
    age: 45,
    visits: 20,
    status: "Complicated",
    progress: 10,
  },
];
```

In the new version of **react-table**, we do not have to memoize the **columns**. We can define it with the help of **columnHelper**. You can read the details [here](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/guide/column-defs).

```js
const columnHelper = createColumnHelper();

const columns = [
  columnHelper.accessor("firstName", {
    header: "First Name",
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor("lastName", {
    header: "Last Name",
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor("age", {
    header: "Age",
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor("visits", {
    header: "Visits",
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor("status", {
    header: "Status",
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor("progress", {
    header: "Profile Progress",
  }),
];
```

Next, we define required states at our component.

```js
  const [data] = useState(() => [...defaultData]);

  // to keep the selected column field
  const [field, setField] = useState();

  // to keep the input search value
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  // required by react-table for filtering purposes
  const [columnFilters, setColumnFilters] = useState();
```

In the previous version, we use **useTable** hooks to create our table instance, here, in the new version, we use **useReactTable** instead. We pass these configurations to make our filter run correctly.

```js
  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    enableFilters: true,
    enableColumnFilters: true,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    state: {
      columnFilters,
    },
    onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters,
  });
```

Next, we create our **select option** tag where we bind the select option **value** to **field** state and the **onChange** event handler to **handleSelectChange**. For the **input** tag, we bind the **value** to **searchValue** and and the **onChange** event handler to **handleInputChange** method.
Inside the select change handler, we need to reset both **columnFilters** and **searchValue** states.

```js
  ...

  const handleSelectChange = (e) => {
    setColumnFilters([]);
    setSearchValue("");
    setField(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setSearchValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    ...
      <select value={field} onChange={handleSelectChange}>
        <option value="">Select Field</option>
        {table.getAllLeafColumns().map((column, index) => {
          return (
            <option value={column.id} key={index}>
              {column.columnDef.header}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
      <input
        value={searchValue}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        className="p-2 font-lg shadow border border-block"
        placeholder={
          field ? `Search ${field} column...` : "Please select a field"
        }
      />
   ...
 )
```

Here, we got the select options list from **table.getAllLeafColumns()**.

Since columns **age**, **visits**, and **progress** values are numbers, we need to modify our columns configurations by using custom **filterFn** options.

```js
const columns = [
  ...

  columnHelper.accessor("age", {
    header: "Age",
    filterFn: (row, _columnId, value) => {
      return row.original.age === parseInt(value);
    },
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor("visits", {
    header: "Visits",
    filterFn: (row, _columnId, value) => {
      return row.original.visits === parseInt(value);
    },
  }),

  ...

  columnHelper.accessor("progress", {
    header: "Profile Progress",
    filterFn: (row, _columnId, value) => {
      return row.original.progress === parseInt(value);
    },
  }),
];
```

And as the [documentation](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/features/filters) said that we need to remember this:

> Every filter function receives:
>
> 1. The row to filter
> 2. The columnId to use to retrieve the row's value
> 3. The filter value
>
> and should return true if the row should be included in the filtered rows, and false if it should be removed.

Finally, it is time to render the table:

```js
  return (
    <div className="p-2">
      ...

      <table>
        <thead>
          {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
                <th key={header.id}>
                  {header.isPlaceholder
                    ? null
                    : flexRender(
                        header.column.columnDef.header,
                        header.getContext()
                      )}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
            <tr key={row.id}>
              {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                <td key={cell.id}>
                  {flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
```

And here is the working code:

[image: Edit sleepy-poitras-6brjuc]

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing... let me implement this in my project.

Comment: Thanks for this, what about filtering unique values from a given column? I see in the API there's 'getUniqueValues' but that only seems to be for rows?

I'm trying to build a status select/dropdown filter outside of the table, all v8 examples showcase a dropdown within the table column